# What is the relation between a triangle’s centroid and its pedal triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, centroid, triangle-centres

The pedal triangle of a point inside a triangle is the triangle formed by connecting the three feet of the perpendiculars drawn from that point to each side of the triangle.

What is the relation between the centroid of a triangle and its pedal triangle? Is it a special triangle center of the pedal triangle(one that is in the triangle center database)?

[image]

Comment: My quick-and-dirty calculations suggest that $G$ may be [X(39162)](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCPart20.html#X39162), the "1st real focus of the [Steiner Inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse)" of $\triangle HIJ$. A GeoGebra sketch seems to bear this out. (Interestingly, the [barycentric coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html) of $G$ relative to $\triangle HIJ$ are $a^2:b^2:c^2$, in terms of the side-lengths of $\triangle ABC$. Converting those coordinates into $\triangle HIJ$-specific values is a mess.)

Comment: @Blue: I get $\left(a^2 (b^4 + c^4 - 6 b^2 c^2 - a^2 (b^2 + c^2))::\right)$ (other ccordinates by cyclic permutation of $a,b,c$) for the centroid of the pedal triangle in barycentrics with reference triangle $ABC$.

Comment: @ccorn: I just double-checked the work (via *Mathematica*), and made another quick GeoGebra sketch. Unless I've misinterpreted something (always a possibility!), I stand by my comment.

Comment: Found: It's [X(373)](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html#X373), confirming my formula (multiply the trilinear $g(a,b,c)$ by $a$ to convert to barycentrics).

Comment: @ccorn: Hmmm ... My (mis?)understanding was that we sought how the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ relates to $\triangle HIJ$, not how the centroid of $\triangle HIJ$ relates to $\triangle ABC$. (See the original version of the question in the [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4673021/revisions), where OP writes *"I know that a triangle’s orthocenter is the incenter of its pedal triangle. [... A]n incenter is the symmedian point of its pedal. [... T]he symmedian point is the centroid of its pedal. What, then, is the relation between the centroid and its pedal triangle?"*)

Comment: @Blue: I see. My calculations confirm that the barycentric coords of $ABC$'s centroid $G$  for reference triangle $HIJ$ are $(a^2:b^2:c^2)$, with $a,b,c$ still the side lengths of $ABC$.

Comment: Denoting side lengths of $HIJ$ as $h,i,j$, I get $h^2 = \left(\frac{a}{6R}\right)^2 (2 b^2 + 2 c^2 - a^2)$ where $R$ is the circumradius of $ABC$.

Comment: @ccorn: I concur with your calculation. The tricky part is getting $a^2$, $b^2$, $c^2$ in terms of $h$, $i$, $j$. Resultants will do it, but the symbolic result(ant) is unwieldy. Best to substitute, say, $h=6$, $i=9$, $j=13$ (in anticipation of looking-up the point on ETC), and solve numerically. (I see now that I overlooked a solution that corresponds to $X(39163)$, the "2nd real focus of the Steiner Inellipse". The ambiguity makes sense; I'm not sure how it's resolved.) ... "Extended discussion" warning. I won't be commenting again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments, User Blue has correctly identified the centroid of triangle $ABC$ as one of the two (real) foci of the [Steiner inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse) of triangle $HIJ$, [X(39162), X(39163)](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETCPart20.html#X39162).

It is helpful to calculate such things using *barycentric coordinates* if you know how to do metric calculations there.
I will omit the details and focus on the part where continuing the straightforward calculation would be inefficient.

As Blue has pointed out, the barycentric representation of $ABC$'s centroid $G$ with reference triangle $HIJ$ turns out to be $G = (a^2:b^2:c^2)$, where $a,b,c$ are (still) the side lengths of triangle $ABC$.

To be systematic, I consider $H,I,J$ to be the pedal points opposite $A,B,C$, respectively (unlike in the figure given).
Side lengths $h,i,j$ are assigned accordingly.
For those, we find

$$\begin{pmatrix}h^2\\i^2\\j^2\end{pmatrix} =
\left(\frac{1}{6R}\right)^2\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 (2 b^2 + 2 c^2 - a^2)\\
b^2 (2 c^2 + 2 a^2 - b^2)\\
c^2 (2 a^2 + 2 b^2 - c^2)
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $R$ is the circumradius of $ABC$.

Note that this implies

$$G' \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \left(\frac{h^2}{a^2}:\frac{i^2}{b^2}:\frac{j^2}{c^2}\right) = \left(2 b^2 + 2 c^2 - a^2:2 c^2 + 2 a^2 - b^2:2 a^2 + 2 b^2 - c^2\right)$$

with equality in the projective sense, i.e. up to a common nonzero factor.

Look closely.
The left-hand side is the [isogonal conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_conjugate) of $G$ in triangle $HIJ$.
The right-hand side is $G$ mirrored over the centroid of $HIJ$.
To verify that, normalize the right-hand side (i.e. rescale such that its coordinates sum to 1) and add it to the normalized $G$. You obtain the equivalent of $(1:1:1)$, the centroid of $HIJ$.

That is, $G$ and $G'$ are isogonal conjugates in $HIJ$ and symmetric about the centroid of $HIJ$. That should remind us of something.

Suppose you are given three pairwise nonparallel tangents to a conic section $s$ and its center $M$. (This uniquely defines $s$).
Let $\Delta$ be the triangle formed by the three given tangents.
Then the foci of $s$ are [isogonal conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_conjugate) with respect to $\Delta$. Furthermore, the midpoint between the foci is $M$.
Conversely, these two properties can be used to determine the foci.

What conic section has the sides of $HIJ$ as tangents and its centroid as center? Right, that is the [Steiner inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse) of $HIJ$.
And we just found out that $G$ and $G'$ are its foci.